# Why does an imported class instance show up as different object in web application?

Tags: python, web-applications

I'm at [example of 52 of Learning Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex52.html) wich consist of creating a text based game. Therefore I have two important modules `map.py` and `app.py` and one `show_room.html` on which I'm working on.

`map.py` contains a room "laser weapon armory" where the user has to guess a 4 digit code.
I'm trying to introduce a cheat code which will reveal the code.This consists of introducing an if clause in `app.py`.

**map.py**:

```
code=("%s%s%s%s"%(randint(0,9),randint(0,9),randint(0,9),randint(0,9))) 
class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def some_other_functions:
        ....

laser_weapon_armory = Room("Laser Weapon Armory",description)
```

**app.py** (read the important part):

```
import web
from gothonweb import map

urls = ('/game', 'GameEngine',
       '/', 'Index',)
some_code

class GameEngine(object):
    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room=session.room)

def POST(self):        
    form = web.input(action="")
    #Here is the important part:
    if session.room == map.laser_weapon_armory:
        if form.action == "you tell me":
            map.laser_weapon_armory.description+=map.code
        elif form.action != map.code:
            form.action ='*'


    if session.room and session.room.go(form.action):
        session.room = session.room.go(form.action)                   

    web.seeother("/game")
```

That if clause at the important part is never getting verified. Mainly because when 'session.room' becomes equal to 'laser_weapon_armory' it shows up as a diffrent object.
i.e:

```
print(laser_weapon_armory) ##<gothonweb.map.Room object at 0x01FDE550>
```

whereas

```
print(session.room)  ##gives <gothonweb.map.Room object at 0x0205E230>
```

Why does this happens, whereas other imports give the same object?

Comment: Where do you compare the code variable?

Comment: @Gregor what do you mean?At app.py there is where I check to see if the users inputted the cheat phrase "you tell me". But in map.py if the users inputs the correct code there is a method add_paths and a go method wich allows to proceed to the next level! You can check it out at the start of the given link.

Comment: Are you sure that form.action gets exactly the correct string ? i.e. "you tell me".

Comment: Try to print out the variable inside the POST method using 
print repr(form) and print repr(form.action)

Comment: @Aladdin It should as there is another other part where I have to get the string "tell a joke" to proceed to the next level and it works fine.

Comment: @Gregor according to command prompt print repr (form) gives:<Storage {'action'=u'you tell me'}>  and print repr(form.action) gives : u'you tell me' the same is true for the 'tell a joke thing'.

Comment: But how is the relation between session.room.description and map.{room name}.description ? As maybe the page isn't re-loaded with the new description.

Comment: How about changing session.room.description as well?

Comment: @Aladdin Well at first session.room=central_corridor then as you advance in the game session.room changes into laser_weapon_armory so when I'm changing the {room name} description I'm trying to change the session.room.description. you can check out the link for more info.

Comment: @Aladdin No changing session.room.description in POST didn't work either! Maybe it changed the same object as map.laser_weapon_armory.desc changed